# How do I assign event handlers to every object with a certain attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, attributes, selector

Basically, I want to assign an event handler to each page number (in a ul) in some sort of loop. Each list item has a certain class and a name attribute. I want to assign the event handler .click() and then inside access the name attribute. Thanks to anyone who responds/views this post, and I would be appreciative if you would also show how to access the name attribute.
I can access all the list items like this I think (accessing each individual one is another process I don't know)

```
$('li[class|='pagelistitem'). //now I need to assign event handler and access 'name' attr
```

Comment: Do you want a different click event for each li?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('li[class|="pagelistitem"]').click(function() {
   var thisName = $(this).attr("name");
});
```

The above code selects all `li` elements with a `class` value with prefix "pagelistitem". It attaches a `click` event listener to each element in that set, and in the event handler function, it gets the `name` attribute of the clicked element.

As mentioned in the comments, you could (and should, in this case) use `this.name` rather than passing `this` into another jQuery object and calling the `attr` method. However, as you specifically mentioned getting the attribute in the question, I wanted to show you the use of the jQuery method.

Comment: Indeed. But I wanted to use jQuery to show how the `attr` method can be used. I was just about to edit the answer to mention that.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I wanted + I loved your explanation